# CakePHP custom function (but not global)

Tags: cakephp, controller

I have a module that handles translations.

It is not bound to any database, the file is purely and simply something like this:

```
$arr["key1"]="text";
...
```

I need to make Ajax calls in order to edit that file. That file will be imported each time a page is accessed in order to deliver any text content that I need (it may not be the best thing of the world but it does the job, and it's supposed to be really fast since there's no "XML parsing" kind of thing, it is simply stored in a standard .php file).

To handle these ajax calls that will have actions like Add/Edit operations, I have made a TranslationController that is Model-less:

```
class TranslationsController extends AppController {
    public $uses = array(); // Model-less
    public $components = array('RequestHandler');
    public $helpers = array('Session');
    protected $translationFilePath;

    public function setItem() {
    }

    public function backupFile() {
    }
}
```

My problem is simple: **where do I put custom functions that are used to open/write/find in files?**

For example I have a function that extracts a key from the line that is being read.

I've seen some posts where we are advised to place the data inside the model but in my case I have no model AND it's these functions are not linked to the data. So it shouldn't be in the model, right? **I do not want it to be global.**

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why are you not using the built in translation stuff that comes with CakePHP and is based on the more or less standard gettext tools? See http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/ and http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a use case for a custom datasource: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/datasources.html.

Personally, I would just create a normal PHP class in the `app/Lib` folder of your application.

Comment: Ok thanks!
It works, I have used a custom library that I load using 
    App::import('Lib', 'TranslationsLibrary');

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not using the built in translation stuff that comes with CakePHP and is based on the more or less standard gettext tools?

What you're doing is just re-inventing the wheel and probably coming up with a non tested customized translation implementation that is obviously lacking feature that CakePHP alreay offers you. For example how do you handle plurals?

CakePHP offers you __(), __d(), __n(), __dn() for translations and the translation files are stored in APP/Locale/ as plain text files and are edited with poedit.

See http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/ and http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html

Comment: Two main reasons for this:
1. My system have to be able to auto-edit the translation files (which can contain HTML) "live", every change is sent to the database via ajax calls.
2. It's directly generated in a PHP file so it's supposed to be faster on read than any other parsing thing.

I may be wrong but for these two cases I don't think CakePHP can do that.